# How to combine two arrays of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am querying an API to get information on users given their email address. For example:

```
emails = [{'email' => 'example1@test.com'}, {'email' => 'example2@test.com'}, ... ]
```

The query hash I pass to the API has to be in this format. The API returns an array of hashes on the information it found for each user. If there was no information it returns an empty hash in that index. The results are returned in the same order as they are queried, i.e. the first index of the response array is the info for `example1@test.com`. A sample response might look like this:

```
response = [{'gender' => 'male', 'age' => '24 - 35'}, {'gender' => 'male'}, ... ]
```

How can I combine my array of email hashes with the response array such that I will get something like the following?

```
combined = [
    {'email' => 'example1@test.com', 'gender' => 'male', 'age' => '24 - 35'}, 
    {'email' => 'example2@test.com', 'gender' => 'male'}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other way to achieve this, basing on @Arup Rakshit's answer:

```
emails = [{'email' => 'example1@test.com'}, {'email' => 'example2@test.com'} ]
response = [{'gender' => 'male', 'age' => '24 - 35'}, {'gender' => 'male'}]
emails.map.with_index { |hash, i| hash.merge(response[i]) }
```

Answer (score 6):

How is this?

```
emails = [{'email' => 'example1@test.com'}, {'email' => 'example2@test.com'} ]
response = [{'gender' => 'male', 'age' => '24 - 35'}, {'gender' => 'male'}]
combined = emails.each_index.map { |i| emails[i].merge(response[i]) }
```

Comment: This was amazing. Worked perfect. I'm entering week four of a new job working with Ruby, which I have never used before, so I didn't even know each_index was a method in the standard library for arrays!

Comment: Or:
`emails.map.with_index { |hash, i| hash.merge(response[i]) }`

Answer (score 5):

My version using [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
emails = [{'email' => 'example1@test.com'}, {'email' => 'example2@test.com'}]
response = [{'gender' => 'male', 'age' => '24 - 35'}, {'gender' => 'male'}]

combined = emails.zip(response).map { |e, r| e.merge(r) }
# => [{"email"=>"example1@test.com", "gender"=>"male", "age"=>"24 - 35"},
#     {"email"=>"example2@test.com", "gender"=>"male"}]
```